# YARN container launch failed

Tags: hadoop, exception, hive, hadoop-yarn

I am unable to run queries on hive. Query fails just after launching map reduce operation (MAP 0% REDUCE 0%). Found the following error in nodemanager logs.

```
2017-03-16 11:53:03,581 ERROR [ContainerLauncher #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: Container launch failed for container_1489041811986_0005_01_000002 : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: slave_1:60805
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy$ContainerManagementProtocolProxyData.newProxy(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy$ContainerManagementProtocolProxyData.<init>(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.getProxy(ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl.getCMProxy(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess it is not able to map hostname slave_1 to its ip.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you (temporarily) add `slave_1` to the system hosts file (with the correct IP), does the error still occur?

Comment: 10.202.13.196 master
10.207.5.44 slave_1

10.202.13.181 slave_2

I have already added these mappings in my /etc/hosts file on both the slaves and the master.

Comment: I reinstalled hadoop with the same configurations and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error and solved it for several days with with the following step:

- open the file /etc/hosts;
- Since your error message is "Does not contain a valid host:port
  authority: slave_1:60805", there should be a value as "salve_1" in
  file "/etc/hosts", for example: "127.0.0.1  salve_1" or "127.0.1.1
  salve_1";
- you need to remove the character "_" or "-" for this hostname and
  then try again. in your example, you can change it to "slave1";

In my case, I removed "-" character in the hostname and then it worked. 
Hope that it works for you.